# how to handle auto_now_add and auto_now in django models

Tags: django, django-models

I have this model where date of second installment and third installment are same whenever i update any of them. How can I update different dates to the second and third installments?

**models.py**:

```
class StudentFee(models.Model):
    student = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    total_fee = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    first_installment = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date_first_installment = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    second_installment = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date_second_installment = models.DateField(auto_now=True) #updates the same date when third installment updated.HOw can update dufferently
    third_installment = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date_third_installment = models.DateField(auto_now=True) 
    remaining = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`auto_now` sets the current timestamp when the row was updated, so all the `auto_now` will be updated whenever `save()` is called.

So don't use it on the `DateTime` fields that you want to update.

```
date_second_installment = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

or you can set a default timestamp

```
date_second_installment = models.DateField(default=timezone.now, null=True, blank=True)
```

[docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now)

Comment: i did that and it saves null after when date added also and display none in the template

Comment: do you want the dates to be filled by default?

Comment: you can add a default, which can be updated later, check the updated answer

Comment: Thanks for the reply.what if i want date only

Comment: You can change your field to `import datetime
date_second_installment = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)`